# Morse code decoding - 1 word

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on encoding/decoding morse code program in java. I'm having trouble with decoding. I'm working strictly with uppercase alphabet and only 1 word. No sentences. When I debugged, the program infinitely loops between Lines 1 & 2. Here is what I have so far:

```
M[0] = .-; to M[25] = --..;

String decode (String m) {
    m = m + " ";
    String temp = "";
    String word = "";

    do {
        temp = m.substring(0,m.indexOf(" "));  //Line 1 

        for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) {
            if (temp.equals(M[i])){      // Line 2
                word += (char)i + 'A';
                m = m.substring(m.indexOf(" " + 1));
            } 
        }
    } while (m.contains(" "));

    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line inside for loop to this:

```
 m = m.substring(m.indexOf(" ")+1);
```